# Characterization of graphene using optical microscopy

Tags: interference, graphene, microscopy

Number of layers of mechanically exfoliated graphite on silicon wafer can be estimated by observing through optical microscope. This is possible due to fact that huge colour contrast between different layers can be differentiated by reflection microscopy. 
But I have reflection microscope which is not giving me colour contrast. So all I can see is homogenous colour with some topography over wafer. Is something missing in my microscope? It contains polarizers and filters as well as adjustable numerical aperture.

Answer (score 0):

The way people usually achieve a large optical contrast is through interference in the SiO$_2$ layer beneath. If this layer is ~90 nm above a Si substrate, you get a large contrast at, if I remember correctly, around 530 nm wavelength.  Do you have a substrate like this to enhance contrast?  If so, are your filters allowing the optimal contrast color through to your camera?  Polarization shouldn't matter.  Even if you have everything set up correctly, it could be a while before you find a monolayer flake, so keep looking and good luck!

Comment: Thank you . I am exfoliating over 300 nm SiO2  Si wafer which I think gives good contrast. I am able to see just the colour of filter used(e.g yellow), as substrate and flakes in light whitish yellow. But all the flakes look the same. I have tried all the filters. The problem is with contrast. Is there some component like DIC(Differential interference contrast) in microscope placed near filters which give us contrast?